# Why does cell2mat convert a cell array into a matrix of characters, instead of a matrix of cell contents?

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have this cell array

```
>> FooCellArray

FooCellArray =

  1×7 cell array

  Columns 1 through 4

    {'Foo1'}    {'Foo2'}    {'Foo3'}    {'Foo4'}

  Columns 5 through 7

    {'Foo5'}    {'Foo6'}    {'Foo7'}
```

`cell2mat()` converts the array into a character array instead of a 1x7 or 7x1 matrix of `'Foo1'` ... `'Foo7'`.

```
>> (cell2mat(FooCellArray))'

ans =

  28×1 char array

    'F'
    'o'
    'o'
    '1'
    'F'
    'o'
    'o'
    '2'
    'F'
    'o'
    'o'
    '3'
    'F'
    'o'
    'o'
    '4'
    ....
```

Why?

Comment: Chars are treated similarly to numeric arrays - what else would you expect? Each of those entries in the original cell is a `1x4` char., it's not clear to me how you'd expect the whole thing to end up as a 7x1 matrix?

Comment: "_Why does cell2mat convert a cell array into a matrix of characters, instead of a matrix of cell contents?_" ... because in MATLAB what you call a `matrix of cell content` is actually called a `cell array`. Different name but the functionality is exactly the same. They could have called it a `cell matrix` instead of `cell array` (cell array can have more than one dimension), but don't let a choice of word confuse you, a `cell array` is the only container type that will let you hold `cell content`. And obviously anything you convert it to will change it's type.

Comment: In MATLAB, the terms “array” and “matrix” refer to the same thing. They tend to use “matrix” when it’s a 2D array and used for linear algebra, but not sometimes also in other contexts. So functions such as this, `…2mat`, really just mean “to a non-cell array”. You should always read the documentation when in doubt. It is really good and will clarify things for you.

Answer (score 3):

`cell2mat` is doing precisely the correct thing as documented here. Each `cell` element is `char` vector of size 1xN. Your overall `cell` array is 1xN. `cell2mat` concatenates the contents of every cell in the "natural" direction as defined by the shape of the `cell` array. Your original `cell` looks a bit like this:

```
FooCellArray = [{'Foo1'}, {'Foo2'}]
```

The effect of `cell2mat` is basically as if you removed the `{}`, so you're left with

```
cell2mat(FooCellArray) --> ['Foo1', 'Foo2']
```

And therefore this gets concatenated into a single `char` vector `'Foo1Foo2'`.

Compare with vectors of `double` instead of vectors of `char`:

```
>> FooCellArray = [{[1,2,3]}, {[4,5,6]}]
FooCellArray =
  1×2 cell array
    {[1 2 3]}    {[4 5 6]}
>> cell2mat(FooCellArray)
ans =
     1     2     3     4     5     6
```

Answer (score 2):

With a smaller starting example:

```
FooCellArray = {'Foo1','Foo2','Foo3'} ;
```

---

If your MATLAB version is >= 2017b

You can directly use the function [`convertCharsToStrings`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convertcharstostrings.html):

```
>> convertCharsToStrings(FooCellArray)
ans = 
  1×3 string array
    "Foo1"    "Foo2"    "Foo3"
```

The benefit of this method is that it will work even if the strings contained in your cell array are not all of the same length. You can transpose it if you want it as a column instead of line vector. Note the terminology of the result type, it is a `string array`.

---

If you MATLAB version is older AND if all the strings in the cell array have the same length, you could convert your cell array into a 2D character array:

```
>> reshape(cell2mat(FooCellArray),4,[]).'
ans =
  3×4 char array
    'Foo1'
    'Foo2'
    'Foo3'
```

For this one, transposition wouldn't really make sense. This result type is a `char array`, which are ok when they are simple vector but they get quite unwieldy once they are in 2D. Mainly because they are not as flexible as strings, each line has to have the same number of elements. So as @Adriaan pointed at, if one of your cell contained `Foo24` then the `reshape` command would error.

Edit: Or as Chris Luengo kindly mentionned in comment, a simpler command to get exactly the same result:

```
>> cell2mat(FooCellArray.')
ans =
  3×4 char array
    'Foo1'
    'Foo2'
    'Foo3'
```

This has the same restriction, all the cell contents must have the same number of characters or the command will error.